# Error: Cannot assign value of type UIImage? to Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, uiimage

I have an ImagePicker which returns an `image`. ([Here](https://pastebin.com/ByQyCQ6N) it is for reference).

However, when trying to convert it to data to store in Core Data, I will get this error: `Cannot assign value of type UIImage? to Data?` and even after trying to unwrap them, I'll get the same error `Cannot assign value of type UIImage to Data` without the optionals.

Here is the offending code:

```
struct AddItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
                    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            let item = Item(context: moc) // contains an optional 'image' property with a type of 'Data'
            
            VStack {
                ...
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                ImagePickerView(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
                    item.image = UIImage(data: image!)!
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

*I have tried unwrapping in every way imaginable, using try?, guard statements, etc.

(to clarify, I am trying to convert the `UIImage` that was returned from `ImagePicker` to `Data` and assign the `Data` to item.image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image is not Data that `ImagePickerView` returns ... its UIImage assign it directly

```
ImagePickerView(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
                    item.image = image.pngData() // or .jpegData()
                }
```

Comment: Running that returns Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage' to type 'Data'.

Besides the fact the code does not work, `item.image` is of type Data. I know the picker returns a UIImage. What I need to do is convert the returned UIImage into Data and assign that Data to item.image.